# Stopping users posting more than once

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

Before posting my form I am checking the database to see if there are any previous posts from the user. If there are previous posts then the script will kick back a message saying you have already posted.

The problem is that what I am trying to achieve isn't working it all goes wrong after my else statement. It is also probable that there is an sql injection vulnerability too. Can you help??4

```
<?php

include '../login/dbc.php';
page_protect();

$customerid = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$checkid = "SELECT customerid FROM content WHERE customerid = $customerid";

if ($checkid = $customerid) {echo 'You cannot post any more entries, you have already created one';}

else

$sql="INSERT INTO content (customerid, weburl, title, description) VALUES
('$_POST[customerid]','$_POST[webaddress]','$_POST[pagetitle]','$_POST[pagedescription]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";

?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do stop form posting to mysql if database contains a specific ID?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2922950/how-do-stop-form-posting-to-mysql-if-database-contains-a-specific-id)

Comment: Just FYI, It's probably not the best of ideas to validate the customer using the `$_SESSION` user id, but then insert the record using the `$_POST` user id.  Someone could very easily spoof another user using this method, even without SQL injection.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`$_SESSION` will clear when the browser is closed out. Therefore, I'd suggest using Cookies for a definite way.

I've updated your code as follows:

```
include '../login/dbc.php';
page_protect();

$customerid = $_COOKIE['user_id'];

$checkid = "SELECT customerid FROM content WHERE customerid = $customerid";

if ($checkid = $customerid) {echo 'You cannot post any more entries, you have already created one';}else{

$sql="INSERT INTO content (customerid, weburl, title, description) VALUES
('$_POST[customerid]','$_POST[webaddress]','$_POST[pagetitle]','$_POST[pagedescription]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
else
  echo "1 record added";
}
```

If you are worried about injection add this tidbit prior to your insert query:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
  $_POST[$key] = addslashes($value);
}
```

Comment: For the record, this is not how I would protect against injection attacks, but it is a quick patch for your script.

Comment: The session would only be lost when the browser is closed if it used a query variable and not cookies (both options for native PHP sessions), AND if the cookie expiration was not set correctly.
Furthermore, your cookie method can be altered by the user with some simple javascript and thus is open to injection, even after applying the tidbit.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing curly brackets `{}`:

```
<?php

if ($checkid == $customerid) {echo 'You cannot post any more entries, you have already created one';}

else
{

$sql="INSERT INTO content (customerid, weburl, title, description) VALUES
('$_POST[customerid]','$_POST[webaddress]','$_POST[pagetitle]','$_POST[pagedescription]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  }
echo "1 record added";
}

?>
```

Comment: Don't forget to also fix your if() statement as that's an asignment and will always evaluate to true (mentioned by thetaiko)

Answer (score 4):

To answer the second part of your question: **yes, you're very vulnerable to SQL injection**:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO content (customerid, ...) VALUES ('$_POST[customerid]', ...)";
                                                     ^
```

[This article](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php) explains SQL Injection and how to avoid the vulnerability in PHP.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the missing curly braces mentioned previously it looks like you're assigning in the if statement, which will cause the statement to always evaluate to true:

```
if ($checkid = $customerid) {echo 'You cannot post any more entries, you have already created one';}
```

Should be:

```
if ($checkid == $customerid) {echo 'You cannot post any more entries, you have already created one';}
```

Also, `$checkid` contains an SQL query string.  I assume you intend to actually run the query and populate `$checkid` with something comparable to a `$customerid` before actually getting to the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the SQL injections (man, read a book/tutorial about that before you start!) and the missing braces after the else, you have two errors in there: First, you don't execute the `$checkid` query, secondly, you only have one `=` in the `if` (so you assign the value of `$customerid` to `$checkid`.

> It is also probable that there is an sql injection vulnerability too.

Why "is possible"? Don't you see that yourself? Don't you write your code in a way that you avoid such issues in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Re: sql injection - any time you trust data from your users you're vulnerable. Take your INSERT statement and sanitize it.

```
$sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO content (customerid, weburl, title, description) VALUES ('%d','%s','%s','%s')",
    $_POST['customerid'], //forced as digit
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['webaddress']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pagetitle']),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['pagedescription']) );
```

Also, you should use apostrophes in your array keys. In double quotes, that'd be:

```
echo "Post data webpage title is {$_POST['pagetitle']}";
```